# Comparing two dates in ruby on rails giving error - "can't convert Date into String"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, date, haml

I'm getting the error while comparing two dates in ruby on rails, I'm using PostgreSQL as my database.

```
exp_date = ps.expiry_date
if Date.today < Date.parse(exp_date)
  Good
else
  Expired
```

`exp_date` variable contains `2014-07-31` value from database.

But while I'm running this code it's giving this error "`can't convert Date into String`" in the 2nd line of my code snippet. But when using directly the date as `2014-07-31`, it's working. Please help me to find out where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only probable reason of getting the error, when `Date::parse` will get an `Date` object as argument. Like below :-

```
Date.parse(Date.today)
# TypeError: no implicit conversion of Date into String
```

I am quite sure, `ps.expiry_date` is giving you `Date` object, not a `String`. As your DB already is giving you the data as `Date` object, you don't need to parse it furthur as `Date`.  Simply write as :

```
Date.today < exp_date
```

Comment: But when using directly using date as `if Date.today < Date.parse('2014-07-31'), it's working

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: @avi Just do `Date.today < exp_date`